# Should I put my not-yet-submitted work on my web page?

Tags: publications, preprint

I am planning on submitting a paper to a journal.  Is it acceptable and advisable to upload it to my web page for public consumption, in the mean time?

Comment: Many of the questions and answers with the [preprint](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preprint) tag are relevant here. Do these answer your question?

Comment: Depends on your field. In math and theoretical computer science, sure.  In chemistry, absolutely not.

Comment: @JeffE: What's so special about chemistry?

Comment: See http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10284/what-are-the-reasons-for-journals-to-reject-any-manuscript-that-has-already-been

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I varies with fields and journals.

Some journals do allows posting preprints on one's webpage, or on a preprint server.

Some not, but they don't care. (And some academicians do put their papers on their websites, even if it is against rules.)

Some don't allow and do care, so putting the preprint on your webpage may disqualify you from publishing this work.

(If it fits your discipline, why not using http://arxiv.org/?)

Comment: I don't use arxiv.org because one has to be invited, and I am an independent researcher with no contacts aside from my old adviser.

Comment: @horsehair Try asking your advisor, or authors of papers you cite.

Comment: One does not have to be invited to ArXiv.  One has to be endorsed.  There's a difference, and the latter often means just convincing one person, not many.